# Why do particles of low mass tend to move near the speed of light?

Tags: particle-physics, speed-of-light

I would have guessed that being massive at all would mean that a particle would not move anywhere near the speed of light except I guess that if they are subjected to forces, their low inertia allows greater speeds than that of more massive particles.

Comment: Decrease in mass increases the wave nature of light which leads to a shift towards the speed of light.

Comment: I think some SR intuition fits here. All things are moving through spacetime at speed c. Some of this is pointed in a time like direction and some in a space.  The mass can be thought of as a coupling that tells you how much you love through space or time for a given mass. More mass and you go more in a timelike direction. Less mass you move more in a space like direction. Very low mass things have most there movement pointed in the suave direction and less in the timelike direction. Therefore they move at speeds near c

Answer (score 2):

Good question. Interacting systems move in the direction of thermal equilibrium. At thermal equilibrium particles satisfy Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution, and their mean kinetic energy is the same and proportional to the temperature. Speed of a particle is a function of the kinetic energy $E$, and in special relativity can be expressed by a formula
$$
v=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{(E/m+1)^2}},
$$
which is an decreasing function of $m$. From the formula, for the same kinetic energy the speed of a particle with smaller $m$ is larger.

Comment: Is this just a fancy way of saying that for something of very low mass, any disturbance sends it on its way and off it goes?

Comment: Not really. Particles with low mass could interact very weakly with everything else, so disturbances wouldn't affect them much. Equality of kinetic energies at thermal equilibrium comes from general properties of Hamiltonian mechanics, so even if light particles interact very weakly, the energy still will be building up slowly until thermal equilibrium is reached